# Using A Conditional Statement For A Menu

Tags: javascript, toggle, conditional-statements

I have a Menu for a website that is broken into two parts.

A left hand panel and a right hand panel.

When clicking one of the two menu buttons the panel slides in from the side and covers the browser window.

At the moment I have got the function working.

Where I am getting stuck is creating the logic for the function using conditionals that say:

- 'If the left panel is 'active' / 'visible' and the right panel button is clicked, slide the left panel out of view while sliding in the right panel.'

and Vise Versa.

Here is the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oez0488h/40/) and below is the code:

NOTE: I've tried to fire an alert when the class name `.panel--oneBtn.is-active` yet nothing is happening. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav_header">

    <div class='nav_header_link_wrap abso-left panel--oneBtn'>
      <span class="nav_header_link abso-left open">Eat.Drink.Sleep</span>
      <span class="nav_header_link abso-left close">Close</span>
    </div>
    <div class='nav_header_link_wrap abso-right panel--twoBtn'>
      <span class="nav_header_link abso-right open">Bookings/Contact</span>
      <span class="nav_header_link abso-right close">Close</span>
    </div>

 </div>

 <div class="menuPanel panel--one"></div>
 <div class="menuPanel panel--two"></div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
function navSlider(){
  var $buttonOne = $('.panel--oneBtn'),
    $buttonTwo = $('.panel--twoBtn');

  $buttonOne.on('click', function() {
    $('.panel--one').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $buttonOne.find('.open').toggleClass('is-gone');
    $buttonOne.find('.close').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
  });

  $buttonTwo.on('click', function() {
    $('.panel--two').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $buttonTwo.find('.open').toggleClass('is-gone');
    $buttonTwo.find('.close').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
  });

  if ( $buttonOne.hasClass('is-active') ){
    alert('Left is active');
  } else if ($buttonTwo.hasClass('is-active') ){
    alert('Right is active');
  }

}

navSlider();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this effect what you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/snookieordie/oez0488h/41/

```
$buttonOne.on('click', function() {

  //added this code
    if ( $buttonTwo.hasClass('is-active') ) {
        $('.panel--two').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $buttonTwo.find('.open').toggleClass('is-gone');
        $buttonTwo.find('.close').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $buttonTwo.toggleClass('is-active');
    }
  //

    $('.panel--one').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $buttonOne.find('.open').toggleClass('is-gone');
    $buttonOne.find('.close').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});



$buttonTwo.on('click', function() {

  //added this code
    if ( $buttonOne.hasClass('is-active') ) {
        $('.panel--one').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $buttonOne.find('.open').toggleClass('is-gone');
        $buttonOne.find('.close').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $buttonOne.toggleClass('is-active');
    }
  //

    $('.panel--two').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $buttonTwo.find('.open').toggleClass('is-gone');
    $buttonTwo.find('.close').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

Comment: That is the exact effect I was going for :) . Thank you for taking the time to answer the question and supplying a edited JS Fiddle.
- Can I ask, did the question make sense, or was it a little confusing? @snookieordie

Comment: @Jargonaut_ You're welcome, there might be a cleverer way to get what you want, but this way is pretty straightforward I think. I think your question was pretty clear, especially with the supplied jsfiddle to look at.

Comment: Beautiful, thats good to hear. I'm only in the early stages of learning ( Treehouse for the win ) Once again, thanks for the answer. I'll keep an eye out for your questions, to return the favour one day haha